# How do I refer the id of schema in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CollageSchema = new Schema({
  collage_name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Name field is required']
  },
  university_id: {
    type: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'university'
    }]
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['autonomous', 'private'],
    required: [true, 'type field is required']
  }
});

const Collage = mongoose.model('collage', CollageSchema);
module.exports = Collage;
```

I have referenced _id of UniversitySchema in CollageSchema, but it will be taking any university_id that will not present in university table. Please help me. Thank you

Comment: is `university.js` model name for `UniversitySchema`? Just like `collage` is model name for `CollageSchema`.

Comment: sry for that mistake.  university is the model of universitySchema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any validation by default in the schema for any Reference Object Id
What you can do is set up one synchronous validation and make a `findOne` call in it to validate.